# Can not connect to azure redis Cache

Tags: c#, azure, stackexchange.redis

I can not connect to Azure Redis cache. I got an exception:An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in StackExchange.Redis.dll but was not handled in user code. I am kind of confused right now. Can I still use the pub/ sub functionality which is available when I connect to local host, Or azure redis cache is just for storage?  I use the debugger and check the multiplexer isConnected property, the isConnected property is false.

```
    static ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Redis"].ToString());
    IDatabase cache = redis.GetDatabase();

            // Perform cache operations using the cache object...
            // Simple put of integral data types into the cache
            cache.StringSet("key1", "value");
            cache.StringSet("key2", 25);

            ISubscriber sub = redis.GetSubscriber();
            const string channelName = "Transactions";
            const string transTblName = "Transaction";
            sub.Publish(channelName, transJson);
```

Comment: What line of code are you getting the null reference?

Comment: @Casey    sub.Publish(channelName, transJson); and             cache.StringSet("key2", 25); I use the debugger and check the multiplexer is connected property, the isconnected property is false. But I am pretty sure that the connection string I copied paste from azure portal is correct, since I had re-copied and paste for more than 4 or 5 times.

Comment: I think I see the issue. Change ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Redis"].ToString() to ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Redis"].ConnectionString

Comment: @Casey I changed this line but still got the null reference error

Comment: Can you verify that the Connection string is what you expect it to be in the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to change

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Redis"].ToString()
```

To

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Redis"].ConnectionString
```